# Riemann's Zeta function. Globally convergent sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, approximation, riemann-zeta

I am writing my master degree work, about numerical approximation for the Riemann Zeta function. In my work I created an approximation that is written below but I believe, that it's identity.

Where:

$z = a + xi$

$\displaystyle \zeta(z) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-z}}\eta(z)$

$E_n(x)$ - generalized exponential integral

Then:

$$\begin{align}
\eta(z) &\approx \frac{1}{2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (E_z(-i \pi(2n-1))+E_z(i\pi(2n-1))) \\&= \frac{1}{2} - 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_1^\infty {\frac{\cos(\pi (2n-1)t)}{t^z}} \, dt
\end{align}$$

---

Why I believe that it is identity, not approximation ?

This approximation is based on researches about partial sum of Dirichlet Eta function. On the photo that is linked below, you can see that I found a function that represents all separated steps and also I know on which values this steps shows. These examples are actually for $z=\frac{1}{2}+200\pi$i. The Red line is the real part, and the blue line is the imaginary part of partial sum of Eta function. My functions are colored in cyan and magenta.

[Image of partial sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNZPY.png)

---

I calculated this integral by mathematica and it doesn't look pretty well. I believe that there should be a better way for it.

[Image of calculated integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jatjk.png)

---

**Question (1):** 
Do these functions remind anyone of any mathematical or physical formulas, etc. ?

**Question (2):** 
If this approximation will be globally convergent to Zeta function, how to show that symbolically if it's even possible ?

Comment: I did some editing to improve your math notation formatting, but putting a $\Big[ \text{left square bracket}$ and a right $\text{square bracket} \Big]$ on opposite sides of an "equals" sign was something I was unsure how to cause to fit together well, and I wonder if that was essentially a typographical error.

Comment: Thanks. These brackets are to separate the identity from the inside of them from general approximation to Eta function. Maybe it will be better to wire it in two separate equations.

Comment: ok, Now I've done a bit more, to make the left and right square brackets have about the same size. $\qquad$

Comment: Double-check my formatting changes.

Comment: “These examples are actually for $z=12+200π$ ”. Is there an i missing here?

Comment: Don't confuse  $$\int_1^\infty \cos(2\pi nt)t^{-s}dt=n^{s-1}\int_n^\infty \cos(2\pi t)t^{-s}dt=n^{s-1}F(s,n)$$ with its analytic continuation in $s$. Integrate by parts to make appear convergence sums. Your approach is well-known from the Fourier series of $(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ in $\eta(s)=s\int_1^\infty \frac{1-(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}{2}x^{-s-1}dx$

Comment: What do you mean by F(s, n) ?